# What does it mean if your request from postman returns HTML body?

Tags: php, rest, api

When I send a request in postman, it returns a html body and it says 404 not found. Does this mean my php server is not running? I am trying to run my php code in visual studio code as a php server.

This is the php file:

```
    <?php 
  // Headers
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  include_once '../../config/Database.php';
  include_once '../../models/Login.php';
  // Instantiate DB & connect
  $database = new Database();
  $db = $database->connect();

  // Instantiate blog post object
  $login = new Login($db);

  //$login->email=isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username']:die();
    $login->password=isset($_GET['phoneNumber']) ? $_GET['phoneNumber']:die();

  $result = $login->read_single();
   $num = $result->rowCount();
 if($num > 0) {
    // Post array
    $posts_arr = array();
    $posts_arr['data2'] = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
      extract($row);
      $post_item = array(
        //'username' => $username,
        'phoneNumber' => $phoneNumber,
        'token' =>$token,
        'tokencreatedat'=>$tokencreatedat,
        'expTime'=>$expTime
      );
      // Push to "data"
      //array_push($posts_arr, $post_item);
      array_push($posts_arr['data2'], $post_item);
    }
    // Turn to JSON & output
    echo json_encode($posts_arr);
  } else {
    // No Posts
    echo json_encode(
      array('message' => 'No Posts Found')
    );
  }
  ?>
```

[image]

[image]

Plus, how do you run php as a web server for RESTful API?

UPDATE: when I put localhost:3000/path in the url in postman, it return 200 which mean its okay. But when I input the IP address, it returns 404.

Comment: Can you post Postman request URL and method.

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth hi, I edited my post. Thank you :)

Comment: Is the PHP url working? http://192.168.0.58:80/login.php open the link directly in the browser.

Comment: @PrabhjotSinghKainth I updated my post again. Thank you :)

Comment: Did you try `192.168.0.58:3000/login.php`?

Comment: @Ivan86 yes. it says "Could not get any response"

Comment: I have never personally run a php server in Visual Studio so I can't really help there, but I would suggest you download and install bitnami LAMP or WAMP or XAMP depending on which operating system you use. It will install Apache, PHP, MySQL then you can deploy your server side files there instead of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

404  means the url you are trying to get is not found !

as per your html,I think your api endpoints ( if you created any or not in both case) has an issue so its showing 404.

I assume you are trying to create an api for user login right ?

at first you should learn about the RESTful Api concept and how to create api endpoints.

[this](https://searchapparchitecture.techtarget.com/definition/RESTful-API) might help

For a quick learning:

create a login_api.php file which will contain php code only. it will take your username / password etc from _POST[], validate your user and redirect you to your home.php

Answer (score 0):

This means that the api which you are hitting have some issues.
So in your case most probably you have some issues with your php laravel code, that's why whenever you are calling that api then html code was returned on behalf of that.
Moreover 404 means that api is not found but then your service is running
Please check your code for syntactical bugs.

> For Restful Api's using php, you can refer [this](https://phppot.com/php/php-restful-web-service/) and [this](https://www.codeofaninja.com/2017/02/create-simple-rest-api-in-php.html)

Comment: Is there any part for the login in the link you gave me? I can't seem to find it. thank you

Comment: Hi @AngelEsguerra , I have provided you the resource from where you can get a nice start when dealing with restful api's in php. Please accept it, if it helps. Thanks :)